# DataBinding does not work with inherited DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a base class and another class that inherits from the base.
The base class has a DependencyProperty  (say "MyDPProperty"):

```
public int MyDPProperty
 { 
   get { return (int)GetValue(MyDPPropertyProperty); } 
   set { SetValue(MyDPPropertyProperty, value); } 
 } 
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDPPropertyProperty =DependencyProperty.Register("MyDPProperty", typeof(int), typeof(ownerclass), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
```

in Window's Constructor i wrote:

```
SomeWpfWindow.DataContext = new ChildClass();
```

and in my Window's XAML code i have:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txt"
        Text="{Binding Path=MyDPProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Now, the binding does not work,Although when I bind it in code behind it works :

```
SomeWpfWindow.txt.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty
                        , new Binding("MyDPProperty")
                        {
                            Source = InstanceOfChildClass,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
                            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
                        });
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of the DP property?

Comment: Don't post that in a comment. _Edit_ the question.

Comment: Similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071086/wpf-how-can-i-make-uielement-support-binding

Answer (score 0):

You are binding a property in code behind. you can give your window a name (for example Name="winName") and define the ElementName in the binding:

```
 x:Name="txt" Text="{Binding ElementName=winName, Path=MyDPProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

there are other ways, for example you can add a StaticResource. this link might help:

http://blog.jayway.com/2011/05/17/bind-from-xaml-to-property-defined-in-code-behind/